# Event when searchview expands from iconified view

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What event(s) I should listen to determine when user clicks on iconified [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html). I want to remove some items (ActionBar navigation tabs, if that is important) from action bar to make more space in portrait orientation.

I've tried OnClickListener, OnFocusChangeListener, OnTouchListener and other events but neither gets triggered by SearchView expansion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since API Level 14 you have a dedicated listener:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionItem);
        ...

    menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when collapsed
            return true;       // Return true to collapse action view
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when expanded
            return true;      // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As always, you can use **ActionBarSherlock** (`com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`) for backward compatibilty

Comment: And if you use AppCompat there is `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener`

Answer (score 14):

I found a way to get that event using [addOnLayoutChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnLayoutChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener%29)

```
private final OnLayoutChangeListener _searchExpandHandler = new OnLayoutChangeListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
            int oldBottom)
        {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)v;
        if (searchView.isIconfiedByDefault() && !searchView.isIconified())
            {
            // search got expanded from icon to search box, hide tabs to make space
            getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Perfect! (though you might want to make use of the passed in `v` instead of `_searchView`)... I couldn't find this method because the method starts with `add` instead of `set` like for the other listeners.

Comment: require API level 11, i want use in level 8.please help

Comment: Also can implements into searchView.addOnLayoutChangeListener();

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `MenuItemCompat`:

```
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Collapsed");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Expanded");

        return true;
    }
});
```